# How to split csv file at some specific rows index (array of indexes)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, csv, split

I am a beginner in python. I have a CSV file that has like 3 M rows and I wanted to split this csv file into some csv files based on a list of indexes

for example I have the list of the index where I need to do the splitting like
Index [0 , 1000 , 5000 , ... etc ]

so I wanted to split the CSV file based on their indexes like the first csv file has the data from row 0 to row number 1000 and the second CSV file has the data from row number 1001 to number 5000 and so on

I tried to use something like that but actually, it doesn't work i think i have a problem in the loop

```
with open('input_0.csv', 'r') as f:
    csvfile = f.readlines()


filename = 1
for i in range(0,len(csvfile)):
    with open(str(filename) + '.csv', 'w+') as f:
        if filename > 1: 
            f.write(csvfile[0]) # header again 
        f.writelines(csvfile[index[i]:1+index[i]])
            
    filename += 1
```

Thanks in advance